# Android emulator inside a Windows Virtual Machine

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Is there an android emulator that runs inside a windows vm? The android studio emulator requires Intel HAXM and genymotion runs on virtualbox which does not support nested virtualisation.

Answer (score 0):

It will certainly work even though I have not tried it yet. Since I run the ios virtual machine as well as the android on the macos virtual machine. View image:

[image: Image run virtual machine]

Comment: so vmware works thanks. Do the genymotion images work on vmware?  Or what do you use as android image?

Comment: @kluki , 
Why do not you try yourself?